# How does Descartes's phrase Cogito Ergo Sum help us better understand ourselves?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

How can we apply the concept of "I think, therefore I am" by Rene Descartes in helping us understand who we are?

Comment: We are "thinking substances": this is the gist of [Descartes' *Cogito*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-epistemology/#CogiErgoSum)

Comment: I am confused by the nature of your question. Descartes's statement says all that needs to be said. Who we are is a broad question, and it seems the only property that we can be certain of is our existence. Whether or not existence is a property is confusing. I'm not well versed in the field.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> How can we apply the concept of "I think, therefore I am" by Rene Descartes in helping us understand who we are?

Descartes' Cogito does not, and was never meant to, help us understand ourselves as human beings, although it does to some extent. Descartes takes the pain to explain in detail that the "I" of the Cogito is not meant to refer to Descartes himself, as would be assumed otherwise, nor should it be understood as any human being asserting the Cogito. Descartes explains that he is using the pronoun "I" in the Cogito to stand for *the thing that thinks whenever he thinks*. This applies to anyone asserting the Cogito for themselves.

Jaakko Hintikka was right when he argued that the Cogito should be understood as a performative utterance. However, he was wrong in saying that it should be understood non inferentially. The Cogito is an inference, and one which is self-evident, much in the same way that a modus ponens is self-evident. It is *performatively* self-evident to the mind thinking the Cogito. It becomes self-evident whenever one thinks the Cogito.

To the extent that our own mind is part of ourselves, the Cogito does help us understand ourselves. This is certainly suggested by the fact that the Cogito is probably the one philosophical argument which is the most widely recognised throughout the world.

However, one aspect of the Cogito is that Descartes didn't do anything useful with it, demonstrating that it is useless knowledge for all practical purposes. No one used the Cogito to prove anything about the material world, not even that the material world exists. Philosophers commenting on the Cogito all seem to agree that the Cogito does not prove to us the existence of Descartes or the existence of Descartes' mind.

Given this, I don't see how the Cogito in itself helps us understand ourselves. Rather, it is common sense that seems to help us understand the Cogito as articulating an idea about ourselves which is in any case self-evident without it. Thus, the effectiveness of the Cogito may be in the fact that it transformed everyone's private knowledge that he or she exists into a very public statement about the existence of the human mind and understood as self-evident by all human beings. Another performative act with possibly more real-world consequences.

---

Why it is that this question is closed? How can it be "off topic" when it is about the Cogito and whether it helps understand ourselves? Isn't that what philosophy is meant to be about?

The rule says this:

> Both academic (e.g., "How does Nietzsche define and characterize 'freedom' throughout his works?") **and informal** (e.g., "Could 'cogito ergo sum' possibly be false?") questions are welcome, but please keep in mind that some questions are too informal and well-trodden to be a good fit for this site (e.g., "What is the sound of one hand clapping?" and "What is good and what is evil?").

So, where is the problem exactly?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!